# File input for select statement in shell scipt

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, sql

I have a text file which has inputs for select statement.

```
sqlplus -s $USERNAME/$PASSWORD@$HOST<<EOF

spool $DIRECTORY/UPDATE.xls

select acc,cr,dr from count
where acc in ***$DIRECTORY/acc.txt***;

spool off;
exit
EOF
```

Please let me know how to use the text file as input at highlighted part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, read the file into an array.

This is for a file containing the values in one single line:

```
read -ar values < "$DIRECTORY"/acc.txt
```

For a multiline file use a loop (one value per line):

```
while read -r v; do
    values+=("$v")
done < <(cat "$DIRECTORY"/acc.txt)
```

According to Archemar's comment, the SQL syntax is `var in ( "value1", "value2", ... )`, so some text processing is needed.

First, quoting:

```
for i in "${values[@]}"; do quoted_values+=(\""$i"\"); done
```

Second, delimiting with commas and spaces:

```
limit="${#quoted_values[@]}"
for ((i=0; i<"$limit"; i++ )); do
    values_string="$values_string""${quoted_values[$i]}"
    ((limit-i-1)) && values_string="$values_string",
    values_string="$values_string"" "
done
```

The brackets around the value list will appear in the here document.

```
sqlplus -s "$USERNAME"/"$PASSWORD"@"$HOST"<<EOF

spool "$DIRECTORY"/UPDATE.xls

select acc,cr,dr from count
where acc in ( "$values_string" );

spool off;
exit
EOF
```

Not tested, so there may be a typo, etc. Comment if you have problems.

Comment: sql syntax is `var in ( "value1", "value2, ...  )` , but you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

very simple way to select from your text file is,

```
cat ${DIRECTORY}/UPDATE.txt |

while read acc_id ; do

       select acc,cr,dr from count
       where acc in ${acc_id};

done
```

that's it.